# JSON: issue with double quotes

Tags: c#, .net, json, json.net

i am trying to parse JSON data returned by an api call. 
parts of the Value may have double qutoes indicating item size in inches.
Example: "description":"size is 7"x 8" ..." (i have truncated the string.)

json.net is throwing exception when parsing that value. 
i am noob at Json and somewhat rusty at C#. 
i am unable to figure out how to solve this issue.

here is the code i am using. i am cleaning up any html tags already and setting the below setting parameters. i have researched a lot but google is not helping due to too many results being returned using words like json escap parse etc.

```
                string value = WebUtility.HtmlDecode(reader.ReadToEnd());
                value = Regex.Replace(value, "<.+?>", string.Empty);                    
                JsonSerializerSettings set = new JsonSerializerSettings();
                set.StringEscapeHandling = StringEscapeHandling.Default;
                set.StringEscapeHandling = StringEscapeHandling.EscapeHtml;
                set.StringEscapeHandling = StringEscapeHandling.EscapeNonAscii;

                myo = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<myboject>(value,set);
```

Comment: "description":"size is 7"x 8" ..." isn't a valid JSON so JsonConvert can't parse it.  Double quotes inside a JSON must be escaped with a backslash - e.g. "description":"size is 7\"x 8\" ...".  Why do you have to clean up HTML tags?  JSON shouldn't have HTML tags in them.  Are sure the API is returning JSON?

Comment: yeah, I think the HtmlDecode call is screwing it up.  If anything, deserialize the JSON, then html decode or encode the individual property values.

Comment: thank you.  the data is actually bad. it has encoded html entities.  so i have had to decode and then use regex to remove html tags. i tried various methods but best was to remove html tags using regex.

Comment: Just because it isn't valid JSON doesn't mean that there aren't plenty of APIs returning it.

Answer (score -2):

Just do:

```
yourJsonString = yourJsonString.Replace("\"", "\\u022");
object o = JSonConvert.Deserialize(yourJsonString);
```

Remember, \u022 is the ascii code for double quotes. So replacing quotes for \u022 will be recognized by your browser.

And use \ in "\u022" to make c# recognize backslash character.

Cheers

Comment: That litteraly changes  " -> \u022